# Resharper ContractAnnotation for null-check not eliminating NRE warning

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I'm having a problem where my extension method, annotated with a ContractAnnotation to tell R# about the null-ness of my object doesn't result in the NRE warning going away. Here's how my projects are laid out:

Project1: JetBrainsExtensions has the R# Annotations class that defines ContractAnnotation

Project2: MyBaseLibrary references Project1 and has an extension method like this:

```
[ContractAnnotation("null => true; notnull => false")]
public static bool IsNull(this object aObject)
{
    return ReferenceEquals(null, aObject);
}
```

Project3: MyBusinessLogic is using the MyBaseLibrary project and wants to do something like this:

```
if (myVariable.IsNull())
     return;

myVariable.DoStuff();
```

The line: myVariable.DoStuff(); get a warning that there's a possible Null Reference Exception.

I've followed the advice listed in many/all of the related StackOverflow posts regarding how that annotation should be written. I've tried:

```
[ContractAnnotation("aObject:null => true; aObject:notnull => false")]
```

and

```
[ContractAnnotation("aObject:null => true")]
```

I've also tried:

```
if (myVariable.IsNull())
    return; 
else
    myVariable.DoSomething();
```

thinking that the if/else construct would save it. No dice.

I'm suspecting the issue is with the multi-project/assembly way I'm packaging it, but I'm not entirely sure. Any idea what I could do?

---

Update: I'm using ReShaper 8.2. I've tried putting the R# Annotation inside my BusinessLogic project AND I've put a new extension method inside that project as well. Neither of those have worked to remove the NRE.

Comment: Do other annotations work? Could you try putting, say, [CanBeNull] on one of the parameters, then use it? If not, check that the annotations namespace is the one that is configured in Code Inspection → Code Annotations.

Comment: Unbelievable! It was my NameSpace issue. I had two namespaces configured in my R# options and only one was checked (the wrong one). If you write your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it. I didn't see any other questions here that were resolved by this approach so I think it could be useful to leave.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out (btw, for single parameter method you don't have to use the parameter name, so your first example should just work now :))

Comment: By the way, I really think this should be a ReSharper warning, if you attempt to use annotation attributes with misconfigured namespace. I opened an issue, please vote on it! http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-413504